# iOS/Swift Equivalent of Android LayoutInflation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, reusability

In Android to reuse views, a common manner of doing so is using a `LayoutInflater` in an `Activity` to get a view as an object which you can then manipulate and finally add to the Activity's content pane.

What is the equivalent pattern in iOS?

Use Case:

I have a group of objects that are to be displayed vertically down the phone screen. I would like to iterate over them, "inflate" a view, and then use the object's properties to set text and other properties of the view. I will then add the view to the main window.

Comment: Why not using a UITableView and UITableViewCell, where you have a ReUseIdentifier to modify each Cell Layouts with your needs?

Comment: @derdida The whole reason I am asking this question is because I understand little about the options available to me with Cocoa. If you post that with an explanation it could very well be the best option.

Comment: Can u be more specific what you want to display with this Views? This is a simple UITableView. http://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/ - but you are able to modify each Cell with your needs (Add UI Elements for example).

Comment: @thatidiotguy You may want to start by reading up on `UITableView`, and following a few tutorials. StackOverflow isn't really the place for general framework questions, especially when you haven't done much research on your own.

Comment: @derdida The views would contain labels and graph components including bar and line charts.

Comment: Then a UITableView would be the perfect UI Element to solve that. Check out the Link in my comment. This is a simple Example - but if you are using google you will find thousends (or try github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comments gave excellent advice.  A UITableView seems perfect for what you describe.  Just search Google for a UITableView tutorial.  Here is an example:

http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/

One the very good sites ti follow in general for tutorial is Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com

he just released his Swift book series:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/swift-by-tutorials

I think he has three new books in total and I am sure they are a bargain for what they will teach you.